# Node.Js server running, but i does not load in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, httpserver

**Hey everyone,**

I decided to learn node.js and i wanted to make most basic http server, but i have problem with that. 
Even tho my code seems ok, even if i copy different code from different tutorial where it works, when i start it, i cant access it in browser. The code executes alright.

I tried to add exceptions to firewall and win defender. I checked the port and its open. I tried reinstalling node.js. I have no idea what else should i do to be able to work with node. It must be something incredibly stupid.

BTW: I am using chromium based Edge, but I tried Chrome too.

````
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');```
````

Comment: Please specify the details (What does Chrome say?). Note the line below the error message, there should be text (sometimes seperated by `_` dashes) and that would help.

Comment: It says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: That means your app may not be listening at the port (or your URL is wrong). You should add an error handler to your .`listen()` eg. `.listen(8081, (e) => e && console.log(e))` (yes, very ugly but you get the idea) to see if there are any errors with that

Comment: Try to change the PORT Number

Comment: Could be an issue for http or https. Try doing it as 
var https = require("https");
and then 
https.createServer(....)

Comment: Ok thanks all for help. I went out and when i came back and booted PC, i added the error handler and it seems to work now. But wierd think is even if i remove the error handler it works. So no idea what i was. But thanks anyway.

Comment: For me, I need to open a port from Firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved it by changing the PORT

Comment: I changed the port but still have the same issue in there